# $elemMatch for filtering out referenced($ref) array objects in mongodb is not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have 2 collections student_details and subject_details where each student can have multiple subjects which I am storing in student_details collection as reference array.

Now I need to fetch Student details along with the filtered subjects where subject_details.status=ACTIVE.

How can I achieve this using `$elemMatch` for `$ref` objects.
I was using something like below but it is not returning any records.

`db.getCollection('student_details').find( { subjects: { $elemMatch: { $ref: "subject_details", status: 'ACTIVE' }}})`

```
student_details
================
{
    "_id" : "STD-1",
    "name" : "XYZ",
    "subjects" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "subject_details",
            "$id" : "SUB-1"
        },
        {
            "$ref" : "subject_details",
            "$id" : "SUB-2"
        },
        {
            "$ref" : "subject_details",
            "$id" : "SUB-3"
        }
    ]
}

subject_details
===============
{
    "_id" : "SUB-1",
    "name" : "MATHEMATICS",
    "status" : "ACTIVE"
}

{
    "_id" : "SUB-2",
    "name" : "PHYSICS",
    "status" : "ACTIVE"
}

{
    "_id" : "SUB-3",
    "name" : "CHEMISTRY",
    "status" : "INACTIVE"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongodb aggregation lookup with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518215/mongodb-aggregation-lookup-with-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbref's are troublesome when used in lookups. but you can work around it with the following aggregation pipeline:

```java
db.student_details.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$subjects"
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "fk": {
                $arrayElemAt: [{
                    $objectToArray: "$subjects"
                }, 1]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from": "subject_details",
            "localField": "fk.v",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "subject"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "subject.status": "ACTIVE"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": {
                $first: "$name"
            },
            "subjects": {
                $push: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$subject", 0]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

the resulting object would be like so:

```java
{
    "_id": "STD-1",
    "name": "XYZ",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "_id": "SUB-1",
            "name": "MATHEMATICS",
            "status": "ACTIVE"
        },
        {
            "_id": "SUB-2",
            "name": "PHYSICS",
            "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you saying it as work around, isn't it a proper way of handling?

Comment: workaround is only the part where you need to convert dbref to an array because dbrefs can't be used directly in $lookup. if you just used an objectid to refence then you don't need the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

because they are in 2 collections you need $lookUp to bring them together...   before that I believe you need to $unwind the Subjects array...  kind of aircode here so this isn't so much an answer as general advice...  the aggregation pipeline is  used to do these in stages...

am assuming you are abbreviating for the post...cause if Subject Details is really just 3 fields your schema is better served in the NoSQL world to just put that info with Student Details and use 1 collection rather than a normalized relational approach