# Aggregate mongoDB collections

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections and I want to join those two collections this is my first collection:

```json
{
    "taskId": "62925ec4e9ebd8e244287299",
    "gebruikerId": "6287cd19af1540ea55212fee",
    "fotoUrl": "<url>",
    "afgerond": false,
    "notitie": "",
    "_id": "62927baabc3b9a3603ad56aa",
    "createdAt": "2022-05-28T19:44:42.559Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-05-28T19:44:42.559Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

And I want to join the taskId of the previous collection on the _id of this collection:

```json
{
    "_id": "62925ec4e9ebd8e244287299",
    "taskNaam": "BodyShot",
    "omschrijving": "Neem een bodyshot uit de navel van Nils",
    "punten": 100,
    "fotoUrl": "<url>",
    "locked": true,
    "createdAt": "2022-05-28T17:41:24.358Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-05-28T17:41:24.358Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongodb aggregation lookup with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518215/mongodb-aggregation-lookup-with-conditions)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in an aggregation stage like this:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection2",
      "localField": "taskId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "tasks"
    }
  }
])
```

This query compare the fields `taskId` in collection1 and `_id` in collection2, showing the join in a field called `tasks`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KjCDnpvBRTB)